# Supreme King Gate Zero's role/s in a Dark Magician deck?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Update (to old question: Does Supreme King Gate Zero's negation apply to Dark Magician the Dragon Knight after the latter has left the field?): Wait I think I get it now. The reason why I couldn't special summon DMTDK was because DMTDK was not special summoned properly, that is, fusion summoned.

If right, please skip next part.

---

With a Dark Magician deck, I was playing against a Blue-Eyes White Dragon deck. I couldn't use Eternal Soul to revive DMTDK, and it may have been due to DMTDK being special summoned with SKGZ.

Could Blue-Eyes Spirit Dragon have had something to do with it? I don't think it was on the field.

Deck: I used [ver2.0 here](http://yugioh.tcgplayer.com/db/article.asp?ID=8363&writer=Loukas+Peterson&articledate=1-17-2018) but Ash Blossom & Joyous Spring instead of Maxx "C".

Programme: I used an [experimental "Ygoproes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC5zeW_N9qU) which I had foolishly tampered with for an unspeakable amount of hours to try to get the program to play an exodia quasar deck instead of a frog deck. I didn't want to say this out of looking like one of those n00bs who think that there's a bug in the programme instead of thinking there may be a ruling issue.

---

So, SKGZ is mainly for Rank 7 summoning as described [here](http://yugioh.tcgplayer.com/db/article.asp?ID=8363&writer=Loukas%20Peterson&articledate=1-17-2018) rather than using its ability? What other roles could it serve? I guess it can be used for Allure of Darkness.

Comment: Mind giving some more detail to your scenario? Describe exactly what cards where involved and how

Comment: Please Ctrl + L your cards with links from yugioh.wikia.com

Answer (score 1):

As your answer indicates that you suspect:

## To Improve The Chance That Dark Magician Is Summoned On Turn 1

In the deck/article you've linked, the purpose of Gate Zero is to be used in tandem with [Supreme King Dragon Darkwurm](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Supreme_King_Dragon_Darkwurm) and [Destrudo the Lost Dragon's Frisson](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Destrudo_the_Lost_Dragon%27s_Frisson) to summon [Odd-Eyes Meteorburst Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Odd-Eyes_Meteorburst_Dragon), and subsequently [Ebon Illusion Magician](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Ebon_Illusion_Magician). This inclusion of Darkwurm/Gate Zero exists solely to achieve this opening move, so that [Dark Magician](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Magician) can more consistently exist on the field on Turn 1.

As the name sort of implies, the "Dark Magician" deck tends to prefer having "Dark Magician" in play; so it is quite desirable to optimize the likelihood of him entering play as early as possible. Gate Zero is a means to this end.

The other capabilities (although, certainly not the intended purpose) of Gate Zero are to summon Dark Magician the Dragon Knight and destroy it in a seldom-occurring pinch, or to set up a pendulum scale from 0 to 5 with Darkwurm, allowing the player to Pendulum Summon any of [Maxx "C"](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Maxx_%22C%22), [Magician's Rod](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Magician%27s_Rod), and/or [Flamvell Guard](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Flamvell_Guard). And as you've noted, of course, it is a legal card to banish via Allure of Darkness.

Answer (score 0):

Supreme king gate zero pops it’s self and another card with it in order to get its effect: special summon 1 fusion dragon-type monster or synchro monster from your extra deck but it’s effect are negated. But let’s say you got enternal souls on the field every “dark magician” in your monster zone is unaffected by your opponents card effects. Ect. Leaving the dragon knight easy to summon. but it be a 0ATK/DEF dark magician vanilla. 0 effects. you would rather pop it at your end turn. Then Special summon it again with ethereal souls to get dark magician the dragon knight full effect. To protect your back row. And field zone.

Comment: Please refrain from using yugioh *slang* terms such as pop and vanilla